# Can I double-click a file to open it with a different program than what's been associated with it?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, notepad++, python, file-association

Is there a way to have separate file-type associations for when a file is run from the command prompt and when it's opened (by double-clicking) from the explorer (GUI)?

I wanted to run python scripts without having to prefix it with `python`. So I ran these commands:

```
ASSOC .py=Python
FTYPE Python=D:\Software\Installed\Anaconda\python.exe %1 %*
```

I also want to be able to open the script with Notepad++ when I double-click the file in Windows Explorer.

I know I can right-click the script and choose 'Edit with Notepad++', but is that the only option if I choose to associate `.py` files with `python.exe`?

**Edit**

Based on @Fabby's suggestion, I created an `edit_or_run.py` script:

```
import os
import psutil
import subprocess
import sys

running_from = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).parent().name()

if running_from == 'cmd.exe':
    subprocess.Popen(['python.exe'] + sys.argv[1:])
elif running_from == 'explorer.exe':
    subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe', sys.argv[1]])
```

and changed the file-type association so that `.py` files open with this script:

```
FTYPE Python=D:\Software\Installed\Anaconda\python.exe D:\Software\Installed\edit_or_run.py "%1" %*
```

**Note:** It works. But when opened in explorer, it takes a second before it gets opened with Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have your cake and eat it too? It's possible, but you'd need to have 2 cakes: one to eat and one to keep...  **:-)**

So in your case, you'd need to associate it with a third program:

```
ASSOC .py=Python
FTYPE Python=D:\Software\Installed\Anaconda\python.exe D:\Software\Installed\MaheshChoose.py %1 %*
```

Where `MaheshChoose` is a Python program that you write that offers you the choice between:

<kbd>Edit</kbd>
<kbd>Run</kbd>

Comment: Your suggestion works. The only problem is that it's slower. I've posted the script that I wrote. When you gave the suggestion, did you have something better in your mind?

Comment: I write C, so that's how I would have done it in C, which is compiled, not interpreted...